# SAS: Create graph with logarithmic relationship

Tags: logging, graph, sas, regression

I have two variables: price and carat. For a regression, I have determined that I should take the log of both variables. Now, I am trying to plot price against carat with a curve that shows the logarithmic relationship. How can I create such a graph in SAS? Thanks.

I have tried the following code, but I don't have anything for offset because I don't have anything to offset. However, I can't seem to get the 95% confidence interval bands without them.

```
 proc genmod data=diamonds; 
 model Price = Carat / dist=poisson link=log; 
 effectplot / clm moff; 
 run;
```

Comment: Do you have any data to add to the question ? Have you looked at `SGPLOT` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a GenMod expert, but maybe a simpler SGPLOT of the log transforms would work.

This sample code shows plots for a linear and log transforms.

```
data prices; * https://www.creditdonkey.com/diamond-prices.html;
input carat price; 
logcarat = log(carat);
logprice = log(price);
datalines;
0.4 890
0.5 1520
0.75 2940
1 5810
1.5 10610
2 19520
run;

title "SGPLOT scatter with linear axes";
proc sgplot data=prices;
  scatter x=carat y=price;
run; 

title "SGPLOT Scatter with log axes";
proc sgplot data=prices;
  scatter x=carat y=price;
  xaxis type=log;
  yaxis type=log;
run; 

title "SGPLOT Linear Regression";
proc sgplot data=prices;
  reg x=carat y=price / CLM CLI;
run; 

title "SGPLOT Linear Regression of Log of variables";
proc sgplot data=prices;
  reg x=logcarat y=logprice / CLM CLI;
run; 

title "GenMod Effect Plot";
proc genmod data=prices;
  model price=carat;
  effectplot / clm; 
run;

title "GenMod Carat=Price (Poisson)";
proc genmod data=prices;
  model price=carat / dist=poisson;
  effectplot / clm; 
run;

title;
```

[image: Example Plots]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The plot I'm trying to make is a mix between the middle-left plot and the bottom-right. So it would show the non-linear relationship, have a confidence & prediction interval around it, but the shape would be the curve drawn in the bottom-right. Here is the data I have:

amstat.org/publications/jse/v9n2/4Cdata.txt